# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in compressor/decompressor .Net Core console program

Tags: c#, .net, compression, console-application

I'm making an compressor / decompressor console program in Visual Studio 2017 and I want to get the filepath by dragging the input file to the console (.txt).

i'm getting the right path for inputStream for Compress() but outPutStream fails and cant find the filepath (FileMode.OpenOrCreate!?!), even if the path is hardcoded.

> Program executes correctly if both variables are hardcoded, but i can't understand why System.IO.FileNotFoundException is thrown by getting input file from dragging the file to console and have the output file hardcoded.

```
  ....
 string outPutFileName = @"C:\bla\bla\bla\bla\gergrgr.gzip";        
 public static void Compress(string inPath)
    {


            using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(inPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outPutFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        inputStream.CopyTo(gzip);                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        string outPutFileName = @"C:\bla\bla\bla\bla\gergrgr.gzip";

        //dummy var, cant find a better way to add '@' to variable set by console.readline
        string filePath = @"test";

        // info info info....
        Console.WriteLine("Drag in txt file");

        // Takes the path from dragged in file
        string idk = Console.ReadLine();

        // instead of of a loop to escape "/", just replace text in filePath
        filePath = filePath.Replace("test", idk);



        Compress(filePath);  

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is actually that your app doesn't have permissions to write to the specified output location.  Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netcore-2.1) for FileMode.OpenOrCreate

> If the file access is FileAccess.Write, Write permission is required.

The below works for me:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly string outPutFileName = @"C:<my desktop directory>\gergrgr.gzip";

        public static void Compress(string inPath)
        {
            using (var inputStream = new FileStream(inPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (var outputStream = new FileStream(outPutFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    using (var gzip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        inputStream.CopyTo(gzip);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // info info info....
            Console.WriteLine("Drag in txt file");

            // Takes the path from dragged in file
            var filePath = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
            {
                Compress(filePath.Trim('\\', '"'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Virus & threat Protection -> Controlled folder access = OFFF. Finally hehe, ty! :-)